# Switch universal app to iPhone only app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, app-store

I have Universal app uploaded on app store,

Later based on requirements I have decided to revamp my entire app with iPhone only, so I have created new project in Xcode(with same bundle id)

Now when I try publish my app on the store it shows me this error of `Target device family` here is the screenshot of error

[image]

I have settled my deployment target to iPhone only in my new project still it shows me error.

Where I am making mistake?

Answer (score 5):

As per the error message in your question, you cannot remove support for a device type that was previously supported.

Since your previous version supported both iPhone and iPad all future versions must support iPhone and iPad.

In order to release an iPhone only version you will need to publish a new app to the store (using a different bundle id), either leaving the current one in place as it is or deleting it.

Comment: If i delete the live available version of store, will i get the name back and can i upload the new app with the same name again?

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this error because of this rule:

> Application update must continue to support all the devices previously
>   supported.

**How to get rid ?**

- Remove this App from app store
- Create new bundle & use it to your new app version
- Deploy App to the store

**Important Note:**

- If you delete an app from the store, then you cannot use its name again for another app. Be careful when deleting an app from the store!

Hope it will help to you.

Comment: Now,not possible to upload new version with iPhone only support?

Comment: Thank you for the info mate, just one doubt, if i upload the new app with new bundle id but can i keep bundle display name same as previous possible?