# Update ios Appstore app to allow only iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store

I have my application in apple app store supporting, iPhone,iPad and iPod (Universal), Now I want to have my app compatible with only iPhone, How to achieve that.(In xcode device family I can check only iPhone and sumbit app sotre, will this make my app only supporting iphone ) Please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35055402/switch-universal-app-to-iphone-only-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is not possible** with the original Bundle ID.

Citing from the doc below:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1623/_index.html

> Bundles must continue to support any devices previously supported.

**The only option** for you is to create a new bundle ID and submit your app with it.

> Removing your app from the store, and uploading the update with a
>   different bundle ID, will allow you to narrow the range of devices
>   your update supports. However the update will be listed on the store
>   as a separate app.